# Existing /root User Directory Not Recognized at Boot

Tags: boot, mount, virtualbox

I believe a recent kernel update may have have caused my /root directory to stop being mounted/recognized at boot.

I am on an ubuntu 20.04 server inside a vbox machine.

Currently `/` directory loads correctly and all other functions of the server seem normal.

The specific problem seems to be that `/root` **user** directory does not get loaded/recognized at boot.

A typical symptom of what I am apparently doing a bad job of describing is ssh functionality.

When my ubuntu vm test server was working correctly the root user ssh key worked correctly because it is stored at `/root/.ssh`

Now, because the /root **user** directory and all of the files inside of it (i.e. `.ssh` subdirectory containing the root ssh pub key) are missing, I am requested to enter a password for root each time that I ssh into the box.

If I boot my vm from a Linux System Rescue disk, then manually mount my root directory `/` at `/mnt/root`... I can cd into the `/root` user directory and see all of the correct files and subdirectories (i.e. `.ssh` directory)

**Question:**
Why is the `/root` user directory not being mounted/recognized when I boot normally?

**NOTE:** If I ssh before the end of my boot sequence, I can consistently get the correct  `/root` user directory.  If I wait until after the boot sequence finishes to ssh into the box... then, I get consistently get the wrong "empty" `/root` user folder.

This is a better screenshot that shows the UUID via `blkid` command proving these are the same disks shown in the screenshots
[image]
My `/etc/fstab` contains:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgadmin-root        /       ext4    relatime,usrquota,rw,quota,errors=remount-ro,grpquota   0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=55F1-E290  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/vgadmin-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

And `lsblk` shows:

```
root@test:~# lsblk
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0   40G  0 disk 
├─sda1               8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2               8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5               8:5    0 39.5G  0 part 
  ├─vgadmin-root   253:0    0 38.5G  0 lvm  /
  └─vgadmin-swap_1 253:1    0  976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

Any tips?

Comment: Be careful.  The directories `/root` and `/` (*root directory*) are different directories with very different purposes.  The `/` is the root directory, where as `/root` is a user directory for the root user; it's contents are usually small thus it doesn't have it's own entry in *fstab*.  Your question mixes those, is that what has confused you?  (your `/etc/fstab` makes no mention of `/root` thus it won't be mounted!)

Comment: What do you mean by `/root user directory does not get loaded at boot`?  That is a folder and not a mountable partition.

Comment: @guiverc  thanks for the feedback.. edited the post.  I am jutrying to figure out why my /root user directory doesn't get loaded at boot... If I mount from a System Rescue disk and manually mount my root directory at /mnt/root  my /root user directory files do exist.

Comment: Your [deleted question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408649/parallel-root-directories) began as an issue with key-based SSH login. I'd encourage you to focus on the actual issue that you are trying to solve - otherwise there's a danger that we just go on a [zebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_(medicine)) hunt.

Comment: @steeldriver  I clarified a bit..

Comment: @Terrance  forgive my misuse of the word "mount"... I guess the better terminology would be "recognized"... When I boot normally.. it seems the vm is creating a new default /root user directory rather than recognizing the already existing /root user directory containing my .ssh subdirectory and ssh pub key.

Comment: I see what you are talking about, but I am at a loss because I am not seeing that both images are from the same system.  I would try to show the UUIDs of the drives to prove that they are one in the same.  Something that `lvdisplay` can show making sure that you are seeing the exact same thing from the system boot or from the sysrecovery you have there.

Comment: @Terrance, thanks for confirming that I am not insane... :-) give me a few minutes.. more screenshots coming.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but if I ssh before the boot sequence completes, I can get the correct /root user folder.    If I wait and ssh -after- the boot sequence completes to ssh, I get an incorrect, "empty" /root user folder

Comment: In one screenshot, you check contents of `/root`, and in the other you check contents of `~`. Maybe, `~` / `$HOME` is not at at `/root`. Can you run `echo $HOME` and `cd ~ && pwd`.

Comment: Since this is a VM, I wonder if you have unintentionally configured it to automount a Shared Folder from the host at /root? Assuming "vbox" means Oracle VirtualBox, check under Devices -> Shared Folders.

Comment: ... and perhaps the difference in behavior is because if you manage to log in as root *before* the shared folder is mounted, the mount fails because the mountpoint is determined to be busy.

Comment: @pLumo  root@test:~# echo $HOME = /root  and root@test:~# cd ~ && pwd  = /root

Comment: @steeldriver  HOLY CRAP... you gotta be "digi-psychic" .... that's it.. I had not one, but two shared folders set to mount at /root/ ... I changed them both to new mount points  , then reboot... problem solved!!!!  Honestly, when I first read your post, I thought you were barking up the wrong tree, because my shared folders have been working perfectly for over a year with zero problems.. I guess something in the recent kernel update finally  triggered my error....  THANKS.. you made my night!